# Bytebuffor operations crash android app in extracting raw data from small amr files

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

When I use mediaCodec to decode an AMR file it outputs a byte buffer but when i try to convert the byte buffer into array of doubles the app crashes.

I tried taking out a single byte form the byte buffer and the app crashes as well. Any operation on the byte buffer causes my app to crash.

```
decoder.start();
        inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
        outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        end_of_input_file = false;

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        ByteBuffer data = readData(info);

        int samplesRead = info.size;

        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[data.remaining()];        
        bytesArray = getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(data);  

here the app crashes.
```

This is the readData method:

```
 private ByteBuffer readData(MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
        if (decoder == null)
            return null;

        for (;;) {
            // Read data from the file into the codec.
            if (!end_of_input_file) {
                int inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                    int size = mExtractor.readSampleData(inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex], 0);
                    if (size < 0) {
                        // End Of File
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                        end_of_input_file = true;
                    } else {
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, size, mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                        mExtractor.advance();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Read the output from the codec.
            if (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                // Ensure that the data is placed at the start of the buffer
                outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex].position(0);

            outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
            if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                // Handle EOF
                if (info.flags != 0) {
                    decoder.stop();
                    decoder.release();
                    decoder = null;
                    return null;
                }

                // Release the buffer so MediaCodec can use it again.
                // The data should stay there until the next time we are called.
                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                return outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

            } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                // This usually happens once at the start of the file.
                outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the getByteArrayFromByteBuffer method:

`````
private static byte[] getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
        byteBuffer.get(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.length);
        return bytesArray;
    }
````


I would like to get the output of the decoder into a double array.
`````

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs/misconceptions in your code.

First issue:

```
        // Read the output from the codec.
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
            // Ensure that the data is placed at the start of the buffer
            outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex].position(0);

        outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
```

Before calling `dequeueOutputBuffer`, you can't know what output buffer it will return. And even if that, you can't control where in the buffer the codec will place its output. The decoder will choose one buffer out of the available ones and place the output data wherever it wants within that buffer. (In practice it is almost always at the start anyway.)

If you want to set up the position/limit in any specific way within the output buffer, you do that after dequeueOutputBuffer has returned it to you.

Just remove the whole if statement and position() call here.

Second bug, which is the real major issue:

```
            // Release the buffer so MediaCodec can use it again.
            // The data should stay there until the next time we are called.
            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

            return outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
```

You are only allowed to touch and use a buffer from outputBuffers after it has been returned by `dequeueOutputBuffer` up until you return it to the decoder by `releaseOutputBuffer`. As your comment says, after `releaseOutputBuffers`, MediaCodec can use it again. Your ByteBuffer variable is only a reference to the same data as the codec can write new output into - it's not a copy here yet. So you cannot call `releaseOutputBuffer` until you have finished using the ByteBuffer object.

Bonus point:
Before using the ByteBuffer, it might be good to set the position/limit for it, like this:

```
outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex].position(info.offset);
outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex].limit(info.offset + info.size);
```

Some decoders do this implicitly, but not necessarily all of them.